# Slightly different answers when changing associativity

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, associativity

With the following simple C++ exercise

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int euro, cents_v1, cents_v2, do_again;
    double price;

    do_again = 1;

    while(do_again != 0){

        cout<<"Insert price in Euro with cents"<<endl;
        cin>>price;

        euro = price;
        cents_v1 = price*100 - euro*100;
        cents_v2 = (price - euro) * 100;

        cout<<"Total: "<<euro<<" euro and "<<cents_v1<<" cents"<< endl;
        cout<<"Total: "<<euro<<" euro and "<<cents_v2<<" cents"<< endl;

        cout <<"\nDo it again? 1: yes, 0: no."<<endl;
        cin>>do_again;

    }
    return 0;

}
```

You can obtain two different answers, if the input is, for example 31.13:

```
Insert price in Euro with cents
31.13
Total: 31 euro and 13 cents
Total: 31 euro and 12 cents

Do it again? 1: yes, 0: no.
```

How to deal with this problem? Is there a rule in programming to avoid or to control this issue in more complicated situations?

Comment: The standard answer to this question [What every computer scientist should know about floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Converting FP results to integers can suffer greatly due to truncation.  Suggest rounding. `cents_v1 = round(price*100 - euro*100);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of rounding issues you should never use `float` or `double` to represent monetary units (they are not exact and when it comes to money people want to be exact).

Try adding the following line to your code:

```
std::cout << std:: setprecision(17) << price << "\n";
```

With your input the result is:

```
31.129999999999999
```

So you either need to create a class to represent your money (not a bad idea). Or use an integer (as integers are always exact). So store the amount of money as the number of **cents** not the number of euros. Then only convert to euros and cents when displaying.

```
class DecimalCurrencyUnit
{
    long   cents;
    public:
        DecimalCurrencyUnit()
            : cents(0)
        {}
        DecimalCurrencyUnit(long euros, long cent)
            : cents(euros * 100 + cent)
        {}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, DecimalCurrencyUnit const& out)
        {
            return s << '€'
                     << (out.cents / 100) << "." 
                     << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (out.cents % 100);
        }
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, DecimalCurrencyUnit& in)
        {
            long euros;
            long cent;
            char s;
            char x;
            if ((s >> s >> euros >> x >> cent) && s == '€' && x == '.' && cent < 100)
            {
                in.cents = euros * 100 + cent;
            }
            else
            {
                s.setsetate(std::ios::bad);
            }
            return s;
        }
        // Add standard operators here for *+/- etc.
}
```

Comment: Maybe `long long`, to be sure that even my country's national debt can be represented...

Comment: @Bob__: If you want to do this in production then arbitrary precision library may be a better idea. If you are just messing around `long long`

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point addition and multiplication are commutative but not associative or distributive. Therefore, `cents_v1` and `cents_v2` may in fact represent different values, as you’ve observed.

One general technique to avoid these types of floating-point gotchas is to use an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library.  There are [quite a few of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software&oldid=713852941), and I’m insufficiently familiar with them to recommend one over another.  Using arbitrary-precision numbers incurs a performance penalty, of course, but until you know your arithmetic is a bottleneck, it’s unwise to optimize further.

If you absolutely must use floating-point arithmetic, there are a variety of rules of thumb to improve accuracy over long floating-point computations; look at some numerical methods texts for more information.  There’s also a good body of research on accuracy in floating-point computation, which has produced some [rather cool software](http://herbie.uwplse.org/).